# Export Menu Behind Report Items in SSRS Report Manager

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

We have recently been experiencing an issue with reports using the reportserver web service in internet explorer. As you can see from the screenshot below, the Export menu is opening behind the report items in the report.

[image]

We are using SQL Server 2014 and our client machines have IE10 or IE11. I have tried adding our report server to compatibility view (which has helped with display issues in the past) but it is not helping this time. I have also tested the same reports using the report manager directly (reports url instead of reportserver) and the export menu works fine in report manager but not through the web service. We have to use the reportserver web service because parameters are being passed in to the report via the url.

I've googled until my fingers are bleeding and have not found anyone else who is having this issue. Can anyone provide any guidance on how to get this resolved?

Comment: I've never seen this before with SSRS 2014 and Internet Explorer. One odd thing is that the list of export options in your screenshot appears to contain both "Excel" and "Excel 2003" - where has the "Excel 2003" option come from? This option is not available in a default install of SSRS 2014, so is it possible someone has manually edited RSReportServer.config and possibly messed something up?

Comment: I added Excel 2003 as an export option a few months ago for a report that needed to be exported to excel in that specific format. I don't believe it would cause this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved the issue for our environment. In the ReportViewer.aspx control on the server, there was the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
```

I commented out this meta tag and made sure that our ssrs server was not in compatibility view settings on the client machines and the export menu started displaying correctly. This issue only recently started happening to us and I'm not entirely sure why but I'm glad it is resolved.

Comment: We were still having some rendering issues even after making the change I outlined above. I stumbled on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25310050/965213 which also helped. Turns out the above meta tag is hardcoded into the dll referenced in the Report.aspx page.